# ASP.Net error System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make application where i can manage customers. So i created database and table tecnici where I can insert all my technicians.

All CRUD operations worked until I created table `clienti` to insert my clients. I made controller, model and view  for `clienti`, and when i run the application it gives me this error **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Cliente' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'**

[Error in ClientiController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txNyW.png) and it gaves me the same error when I try to load all clients ftom table  `clienti` [errore in TecniciController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsiW7.png)

This is code for ClientiController

```
public class ClientiController: Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public ClientiController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var datiClienti = _db.tboClienti.ToList();
            return View(datiClienti);
        }

        public IActionResult CreareCliente()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreareCliente(Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Add(cliente);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(cliente);
        }
    }
```

This is model Cliente

```
public class Cliente
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci il nome di proprietario della azienda")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci il cognome di proprietario della azienda")]
        [Display(Name = "Cognome")]
        public string Cognome { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Azienda")]
        public string Nome_azienda { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inserisci numero  cellulare della Azienda")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$",
           ErrorMessage = "Numero non valido")]
        public string Cellulare { get; set; }
    }
```

I have my connectionstring into `appsettings.json`

And this is the calass where I configure db:

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base (options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Tecnico> tboTecnici { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cliente> tboClienti { get; set; }
    }
```

Until was only one table (table: `tecnici`) it did not make me problems. When I create controller model and view for table tboClienti it gives me the error.

[This is table tboClienti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK2WD.png)

[And this is tboTecnici](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjPC.png)

Any suggestions how to fix this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have primary key defined for your entity. Do you use code first approach?

Comment: I have primary key. I just update my question with photo of my tables https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK2WD.png

Comment: Yeah, but EF doesn't know which property is your primary key. You need to specify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception text says you have to define a primary key or explicitly say that this table has no primary key.

I suggest you to make a key like

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

or with a Guid instead of the integer - that has the advantage that Guids can be generated before saving but it is less readable than a number - as you want.

```
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: [Key]
public Guid Id {get;set;}  

I should add it only in Model Tecnici?

 Because when i insert it in Model Clienti it gaves me the same error.

Comment: You have to add the `Id` field to the actual DB table, as well as the model that represents it. Make sure the types match (e.g. "Guid" in the model, "uniqueidentifier" in a SQL Server DB, if that's what you're using).

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a primary key in your client class.

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: But my Id is  primary key **auto increment**. I don't want that the user insert ID

Comment: User does not have influence on the ID property, just use the ID prop as a hidden field in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify that the column `Id` is your primary key, and also specify that is auto incremented by the SQL server

```cs
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

That way once you save your entity to the database, the `Id` will be automatically populated with the new generated value

Answer (score 0):

If you face this Error and the [Key] Attribute didn't solve the issue.

You can try including the column order feature. This solves EntityType of No Key Defining Errors.

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Include `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace in your Model Class.

The `key` needs to be property and public.